# HTML CSS : <li> items are duplicating resulting in duplicate images

Tags: php, html, wordpress, duplicates, html-lists

For some reason the `<li>` items are duplicating in my wordpress site. I have isolated the code in the header.php file to what you see below. I also don't think the problem is in the CSS but I cant figure out what is causing this.

The code going in looks like this:

```
        <div id="toplinks">
        <ul id="links">
            <li><a class="narch"/>  </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.torhs.com" title="TORHS" class="torhs" target="_blank" /> </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.omrha.com" title="OMRHA" class="omhra" target="_blank" /></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jangosportswear.com" title="JANGO" class="jango" target="_blank" /> </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.statewarshockey.com" title="State Wars" class="statewars" target="_blank" /> </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Wicked Biscuit" class="wickedbiscuit" target="_blank" /> </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Rattlers" class="rattlers" target="_blank" /> </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.revisionhockey.com" title="Revision Hockey" class="revision" target="_blank" /> </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.rollerhockeyalliance.com" title="RHA" class="RHA" target="_blank" /> </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.rinkrathockey.com" title="Rink Rat" class="rinkrat" target="_blank" /> </li>

            <li><a href="http://www.rocketpuck.com" title="Rocket Puck" class="rocketpuck" target="_blank" /> </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.missionhockey.com" title="Mission" class="mission" target="_blank" /> </li> 
        </ul>
    </div> <!--clooses toplinks-->
```

The code coming out (taken using firebug) looks like this.

```
<ul id="links">
<li>
<a class="narch"> </a>
</li>
<a class="narch"> </a>
<li>
<a class="narch"></a>
<a class="torhs" target="_blank" title="TORHS" href="http://www.torhs.com"> </a>
</li>
<a class="torhs" target="_blank" title="TORHS" href="http://www.torhs.com"> </a>
<li>
<a class="torhs" target="_blank" title="TORHS" href="http://www.torhs.com"></a>
<a class="omhra" target="_blank" title="OMRHA" href="http://www.omrha.com"></a>
</li>
<a class="omhra" target="_blank" title="OMRHA" href="http://www.omrha.com"> </a>
<li>
<a class="omhra" target="_blank" title="OMRHA" href="http://www.omrha.com"></a>
<a class="jango" target="_blank" title="JANGO" href="http://www.jangosportswear.com"> </a>
</li>
<a class="jango" target="_blank" title="JANGO" href="http://www.jangosportswear.com"> </a>
<li>
<a class="jango" target="_blank" title="JANGO" href="http://www.jangosportswear.com"></a>
<a class="statewars" target="_blank" title="State Wars" href="http://www.statewarshockey.com"> </a>
</li>
<a class="statewars" target="_blank" title="State Wars" href="http://www.statewarshockey.com"> </a>
<li>
<a class="statewars" target="_blank" title="State Wars" href="http://www.statewarshockey.com"></a>
<a class="wickedbiscuit" target="_blank" title="Wicked Biscuit" href="#"> </a>
</li>
<a class="wickedbiscuit" target="_blank" title="Wicked Biscuit" href="#"> </a>
<li>
<a class="wickedbiscuit" target="_blank" title="Wicked Biscuit" href="#"></a>
<a class="rattlers" target="_blank" title="Rattlers" href="#"> </a>
</li>
<a class="rattlers" target="_blank" title="Rattlers" href="#"> </a>
<li>
<a class="rattlers" target="_blank" title="Rattlers" href="#"></a>
<a class="revision" target="_blank" title="Revision Hockey" href="http://www.revisionhockey.com"> </a>
</li>
<a class="revision" target="_blank" title="Revision Hockey" href="http://www.revisionhockey.com"> </a>
<li>
<a class="revision" target="_blank" title="Revision Hockey" href="http://www.revisionhockey.com"></a>
<a class="RHA" target="_blank" title="RHA" href="http://www.rollerhockeyalliance.com"> </a>
</li>
<a class="RHA" target="_blank" title="RHA" href="http://www.rollerhockeyalliance.com"> </a>
<li>
<a class="RHA" target="_blank" title="RHA" href="http://www.rollerhockeyalliance.com"></a>
<a class="rinkrat" target="_blank" title="Rink Rat" href="http://www.rinkrathockey.com"> </a>
</li>
<a class="rinkrat" target="_blank" title="Rink Rat" href="http://www.rinkrathockey.com"> </a>
<li>
<a class="rinkrat" target="_blank" title="Rink Rat" href="http://www.rinkrathockey.com"></a>
<a class="rocketpuck" target="_blank" title="Rocket Puck" href="http://www.rocketpuck.com"> </a>
</li>
<a class="rocketpuck" target="_blank" title="Rocket Puck" href="http://www.rocketpuck.com"> </a>
<li>
<a class="rocketpuck" target="_blank" title="Rocket Puck" href="http://www.rocketpuck.com"></a>
<a class="mission" target="_blank" title="Mission" href="http://www.missionhockey.com"> </a>
</li>
<a class="mission" target="_blank" title="Mission" href="http://www.missionhockey.com"> </a>
</ul>
<a class="mission" target="_blank" title="Mission" href="http://www.missionhockey.com"> </a>
</div>
<a class="mission" target="_blank" title="Mission" href="http://www.missionhockey.com"> </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be confusing HTML with XML-style markup.

The most basic link is marked up like so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

The `title` attribute is actually what shows for the element's tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="narch"/>
```

Close your anchors correctly